# How to add code to `head` with WordPress 5.9 FSE (Full Site Editing)

Tags: block-editor, full-site-editing

Like adding Google Analytics code, and some other things surrounding the `<head>` tag, how's all this done in FSE as there's no `header.php`? Should I use `functions.php` for everything?

(Also can somebody make a fse tag in stackexchange?)

Comment: Does the [`wp_head` action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) still work?

Comment: @kero yes it does. Looks like my `funcitons.php` will be kinda ugly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand the `wp_head` and `wp_footer` actions should still work under FSE in WP 5.9+, through the [template canvas](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/lib/compat/wordpress-5.9/template-canvas.php) PHP file that's loaded through the [`locate_block_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_block_template/). That PHP file contains the basic HTML structure and there we find e.g. the familiar `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` function calls that we usually had in the old `footer.php` and `header.php` theme files. The current block template HTML from [`get_the_block_template_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_block_template_html/) is now displayed within the body tag from the template canvas.

So in FSE use e.g. the theme's `functions.php` file or a custom plugin to add your `wp_head` and `wp_footer` actions in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

When I was creating a FSE theme I had the same question. I found that the Shorcode Block is an easy way to insert coding into any template. So for a shortcode [custom_content] this is the coding required in the functions file or move the code to a custom.php file in another directory.

```
/assets/custom.php
    function add_custom_content() {
        ...
        return [new code...];
    }
    add_shortcode('custom_content', 'add_custom_content');
    
functions.php
require get_template_directory() . '/assets/custom.php';
```

Edit: Ok so FSE templates are part of the <body> so this didn't answer the question.

To get code into the <head> - this works

```
    function add_to_head() {
        echo '<script> /* code... */ </script>';
    }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_to_head' );
```